# How is Windows ICS service different from Linux-based NAT & routing when I want to hide my LAN structure from ISP?

Tags: firewall, routing, iptables, nat

**Background**

I've been using a WIFI-router as my home gateway perfectly until my ISP appears to restrain the number of connected devices. And currently there is not any realistic upgrade plan from the ISP for more devices. So I'm trying to setup a Linux-based NAT router.

**Components**

1. a Raspberry Pi 2 model B (RPi), with a built-in ethernet adapter and 4 USB port.
2. a USB 100Mbit ethernet adapter.
3. a switch with 4 ports.

**Hardware setup**

The built-in ethernet adapter of RPi, i.e., eth0 will be used as its WAN adapter.
A switch will be plugged to the RPi via a USB ethernet adapter, i.e., eth1. So this USB ethernet adapter is supposed to work as a LAN adapter.
Wired devices such as my laptop and WIFI-router will be connected via the switch while wireless devices will be connected via the WIFI-router obviously.

**Software setup**

I have configured dnsmasq on the RPi simply to provide both the DHCP and DNS services.
The WAN adapter (eth0) obtains IP address and DNS from ISP by DHCP.
The LAN adapter (eth1) is configured with static address 10.0.1.1/24.
Routing and NAT are configured as:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I also turned on the ipv4 forwarding.

**Tests and results**

***Test 1.***

First I *SIMULATE* the ISP with my WIFI-router, namely, I plug the WAN adapter of the RPi to one of the LAN slots of the router. Then I connect my laptop directly to the LAN adapter of the RPi.
My laptop obtains an IP address 10.0.1.129 by DHCP just as I expected.
I can ping from my laptop to the router via the RPi successfully.
I can also access the administrative web page served by the router from my laptop.
So everything works well.

***Test 2.***

I plug the RPi to the *REAL* ISP cable via its WAN adapter. The laptop is still plugged to the RPi's LAN adapter.
I have internet connection on the RPi.
I can got WAN hostname resolved from my laptop but I can't ping it and open any WAN web pages there.
So Test 2 fails.

***Later I take another approach.***

I have a bi-modal USB WIFI dongle which can work as a WIFI-client or a WIFI-router when plugged to a computer running Windows XP/7/8. I plug the ISP cable to my laptop so that I can access internet from my laptop. Then I plug the USB WIFI dongle to my laptop and configure it as a WIFI-router. In this approach my iPhone, iPad and laptop can share the internet connection successfully. I believe this approach is implemented by Windows ICS (internet connection sharing) service.

**So here are my two questions:**

1. What's the difference between Windows ICS service and Linux-based NAT & Routing especially the configuration that I implemented? I thought Windows ICS is just a subset of the NAT.
2. Is there any chance that I can get my RPi to work as my home gateway instead of my laptop? After all the laptop consumes much more power.